# Sharing scope/data between directive controller and a child directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm opening a custom modal (using angular-bootstrap):

```
$modal.open({
    // templateUrl, etc
    controller: 'DemoModalController'
});
```

It has form handling methods and data loaded to its controller/scope:

```
modals.controller('DemoModalController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

   $scope.formData = {};
});
```

The template of this modal has a `<div location-field>` element, it's a custom field I've defined as a directive.

```
    locationField.directive('locationField', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            templateUrl: 'location-field.html',
            controller: 'LocationFieldController'
        };
    });
```

I'm trying to find the best solution for accessing data in the form fields inside the `locationField` directive.

If there's an element inside `<input type="text" ng-model="location.x">`, I want the `location` to be accessible to the `DemoModalController`

I've tried setting the directive to `scope: false`, `scope: { location: '=' }` (and setting a location object in the controller), and also `scope: { location: '@' }` but none seem to work.

The only way that works so far is calling `$scope.$$childTrail.location` from the modal controller scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try passing the field like:

```
<div location = "{{location}}">
```

Comment: My final solution involved this so I'll mark it as the answer. In the parent template I'm passing `<location model="model" />` and in the child directive I can attach the `<input ng-model="model.fieldName" />`. I need to ensure the directive has `scope: { model: '=' }`, but was able to get this working.